# Using .text() right in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating a form with about hundred different inputs to be filled and calculated.

I have a way to do it manually which is working (see JS code).
But its not really nice when i add about 100 input fields, so i want the script to set the .text automatically for all calculations in a for loop. But i don't know how i can use the for-loop together with the `$(ABC).text(XYZ);` - i have tried it with `$("#w+i+g").text(v+i);` but it didn't work.

The `.text(v+i)` seem to be the problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wohnzimmer").keyup(function() {
    v0 = $("#w0").val() * 4;
    //$("#w0g").text(v0); //THATS THE MANUAL WAY I DID BEFORE

    v1 = $("#w1").val() * 4;
    //$("#w1g").text(v1); //THATS THE MANUAL WAY I DID BEFORE


    for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
      $("#w" + i + "g").text(v0); //THATS THE AUTOMATIC WAY I WANT TO DO - BUT HOW? .text(v+i+) DOESNT WORK       
    };

    vGes = v0 + v1;
    $("#wGes").text(vGes);
  });
});
```

```css
.text {
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.restText {
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.raumeinheitInput {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form id="wohnzimmer">
    <div>
      <div class="text">
        Sofa, Couch, Liege je Sitz
      </div>
      <div class="restText">
        <input id="w0" type="text" class="raumeinheitInput" value="0" /> * 4 = <span id="w0g"> kA </span> RE
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="text">
        Couch L-Form
      </div>
      <div class="restText">
        <input id="w1" type="text" class="raumeinheitInput" value="0" /> * 4 = <span id="w1g"> kA </span> RE
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text">
      Raumeinheiten Gesamt: <span id="wGes"> kA </span>
    </div>
  </form>

</body>
```

I hope you understand my problem and i'm sure there is a simple way I do not know :(

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Define `it didn't work`.. what was the result?

Comment: @vsync he wants v0, v1, v2 ... so sth like window["v" + i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".raumeinheitInput").each(function(){
  $("#"+ this.id + "g" ).text($(this).val() * 4);
});
```

Theres no need to store the results in variables. Just iterate over the inputs, then get the element of their id + *g* , and set its content. If the ids are not related, a 2d table may does it:

```
 [["w0", "w0g"],
  ["w1", "w1g"],
  ["w2", "w2g"]
 ].forEach(([from,to])=> $("#"+from).text($(" #"+to).val() *4 ));
```

Comment: `$(".raumeinheitInput").each(function(){
  $("#"+ this.id + "g" ).text($(this).val() * 4);
});`

That helped me a lot.
Thank you :)

Comment: @kjarudi glad to help ;) , if it answered your question ypu could check the green checkmark ;)